# AppMetrics health checks in asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to apply health checks from AppMetrics library on my asp.net core web api application. I have tried on multiple ways but with no success.

In Program.cs

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseHealth()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

In Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<HealthCheck, SampleHealthCheck>();

        var metrics = new HealthBuilder()
            .HealthChecks.AddCheck(new SampleHealthCheck())
            .HealthChecks.AddCheck("DatabaseConnected", 
                () => new ValueTask<HealthCheckResult>(HealthCheckResult.Healthy("Database Connection OK")))
            .HealthChecks.RegisterFromAssembly(services)
            .Build();

        services.AddHealth(metrics);
        services.AddHealthEndpoints();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHealthAllEndpoints();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

The error which I am still receiving looks the following:

```
    System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
  at at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
  at at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetDefinedTypes()
  at at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
  at App.Metrics.Health.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Internal.DefaultHealthCheckTypeProvider.<>c.<get_HealthCheckTypes>b__5_0(Assembly a) in C:\projects\microsoftextensions\src\App.Metrics.Health.Extensions.DependencyInjection\Internal\DefaultHealthCheckTypeProvider.cs:25
  at at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at App.Metrics.Health.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Internal.HealthChecksAsServices.AddHealthChecksAsServices(IServiceCollection services, IEnumerable`1 types) in C:\projects\microsoftextensions\src\App.Metrics.Health.Extensions.DependencyInjection\Internal\HealthChecksAsServices.cs:27
  at App.Metrics.Health.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Internal.HealthChecksAsServices.AddHealthChecksAsServices(IServiceCollection services, IEnumerable`1 assemblies) in C:\projects\microsoftextensions\src\App.Metrics.Health.Extensions.DependencyInjection\Internal\HealthChecksAsServices.cs:53
  at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionHealthCheckBuilderExtensions.RegisterFromAssembly(IHealthCheckBuilder healthCheckBuilder, IServiceCollection services, DependencyContext dependencyContext) in C:\projects\microsoftextensions\src\App.Metrics.Health.Extensions.DependencyInjection\ServiceCollectionHealthCheckBuilderExtensions.cs:34
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HealthAspNetWebHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<ConfigureHealth>b__0(WebHostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services) in C:\projects\aspnetcorehealth\src\App.Metrics.AspNetCore.Health.Hosting\HealthAspNetWebHostBuilderExtensions.cs:113
  at at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
  at at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
  at WebApiAppMetrics.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args) in C:\DEV\AspnetWebApiAppMetricsPlayground\AspnetWebApiAppMetricsPlayground\WebApiAppMetrics\Program.cs:24
  at WebApiAppMetrics.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\_TEST_\AspnetWebApiAppMetricsPlayground\AspnetWebApiAppMetricsPlayground\WebApiAppMetrics\Program.cs:20
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps below for a working demo:

1. Create a .Net Core 2.1 Web Project
2. Install Package `App.Metrics.AspNetCore.Health`
3. `Program.cs`

   ```
   public class Program
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
       }

       public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureHealthWithDefaults(
               builder =>
               {
                   builder.HealthChecks.AddCheck("DatabaseConnected",
               () => new ValueTask<HealthCheckResult>(HealthCheckResult.Healthy("Database Connection OK")));
               })
               .UseHealth()
               .UseStartup<Startup>();
   }
   ```
4. Access `https://localhost:44343/health` to check the result.

For `App.Metrics.AspNetCore.Health`, and `UseHealth()`, it has automatically scan the executing assembly, as well as any of it’s referenced assemblies with a dependency on App.Metrics.*, for health check implementations and register them.

For `SampleHealthCheck`, if you inherit from `HealthCheck`, there is no need to register it explictly. `AppMetrics` will register it for you.

Refer [HEALTH](https://www.app-metrics.io/web-monitoring/aspnet-core/health/#getting-started)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Generally, I know the documentation and project website. I have managed to resolve the problem. I have been using .net core 2.0 instead of the newer one. After installing newer version the problem disappeared so there is some problem with backward compability for .net core 2.0. Anyway, thank you for your help.